# c++ \ Compile successful, can't debug - STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND

Tags: c++, debugging, dll, visual-studio-2005, symbols

Why can't I debug my application (though compile is good)?
1. Does it really need windows dlls? how can I attach them?
2. Why can't it recognize my Dlls? It resides in the same folder..

(VS2005, main program is c++ with c# code).

**The Error is - Debugger:: An unhandled non-continuable STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND exception was thrown during process**

```
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'D:\Folder\Transcriber.exe', Symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll', No symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll', No symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'D:\Folder\RegAccess71.dll', No symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC80.MFC_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4027_x-ww_b779ebd5\mfc80.dll', No symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC80.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_x-ww_e6967989\msvcr80.dll', No symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll', No symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\gdi32.dll', No symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\user32.dll', No symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\shlwapi.dll', No symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\advapi32.dll', No symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\rpcrt4.dll', No symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\secur32.dll', No symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\oleaut32.dll', No symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll', No symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'D:\Folder\MetaData.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\mscoree.dll', No symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\imm32.dll', No symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\lpk.dll', No symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\usp10.dll', No symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\HookDll.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC80.MFCLOC_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4027_x-ww_0cc904d3\mfc80ENU.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.42_x-ww_f75eb16c\msvcr80d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC80.DebugMFC_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.42_x-ww_c8452471\mfc80d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.42_x-ww_f75eb16c\msvcm80d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'D:\Folder\ITSConfigWrapper.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'D:\Folder\InfoTransformerWrapper.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\dbghelp.dll', No symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\version.dll', No symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC80.DebugMFC_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.42_x-ww_c8452471\mfc80ud.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\shell32.dll', No symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC80.ATL_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_x-ww_473666fd\ATL80.dll', No symbols loaded.
'Transcriber.exe': Loaded 'D:\Folder\LoggerClientD.dll', No symbols loaded.
**Debugger:: An unhandled non-continuable STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND exception was thrown during process** load
The program '[4224] Transcriber.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135).
```

Comment: Do you know which DLL it's failing to load? (maybe try sysinternals procmon or filemon during the load?) Have you given the DLL the same name as one that lives in system32, e.g. Security.dll, that it might think you're trying to override for malicious reasons? Try opening your binary in Dependency Walker or similar and see if that shows any errors too.

Comment: Dependency walker seems like a great path. I did have couple of alerts there. now the only file I struggle there is MFC71D.dll - what is the fastest and safest way to get this file? (I don't have it on my machine). Thanks.

Comment: That's a debugging version of MFC from Visual Studio 2003. You really don't want to be mixing MFC versions - you should probably work out which DLL is including it then try and get a new version of that DLL built with 2005 - i.e. port it yourself if you've got the code.

Comment: Thanks. I do have the code of those DLLs that uses MFC (I searched for MFC string in the project). but I must say - those projects are compiled together with my target project (I do "Rebuild Solution") - is it possible they are compiled with different compiler? Where exactly do I check the compiler type for that matter?

Comment: @Rup are you sure? VC80 is VS2003, isn't it?

Comment: @Alan - VC 8 is VS 2005.  VS 2003 is VC 7.1.

Comment: Finally, I got from the web the missing dll, located it in the bin folder and it is working! thanks everyone for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is being returned because a DLL file required for your application to run is missing. Check your linker settings, and make sure all the DLLs your application depends on are where they're supposed to be (i.e. in the same folder as the executable, or elsewhere in the DLL search path.)

Comment: Thanks.  There are two type of files here - windows files and my files. all my files are near the exe (in bin\debug). I tried to play a bit with Linker>Input>"Additional Dependencies" and all my dlls appears there - actually they appear as *.lib files. If you have more suggestions on my possible next steps I'd appreciate that!

Comment: try something like http://www.dependencywalker.com/ - it will show you which dll is missing...

Comment: See Rup's comment above; try to figure out what file the process is failing to load.

Answer (score 2):

You're loading both the release and debug versions of MFC and the C runtime. That never works, sadly. You need to use release mode of all DLLs or debug mode of all DLLs.